# Reading delimited text file?

Tags: c#, .net, io

I am trying to read from a delimited text file, but everything is returned in in one row and one column.

My connections string is

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
    Path.GetDirectoryName(@textBox1txtPath.Text) + ";" + 
    "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Format=Delimited(|)\"");
```

And my text file reads:

```
ItemNumber|ProductStatus|UPC
0000012|closed|2525
```

Please assist

Comment: Have a look at the [FileHelpers](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/) nuget package. The library is documented [here](http://www.filehelpers.com/quick_start.html). This library make parsing delimited files a breeze.

Answer (score 4):

i don't know exactly what do you need, but you can do this:

if you have `string str` with the whole text in it you can do

```
string[] lines = str.Split('\n');// split it to lines;
```

and then for each line you can do

```
string[] cells = line.Split('|');// split a line to cells
```

if we take it to the next level we can do:

```
public class line
{
  public int ItemNumber { get; set; }
  public string ProductStatus { get; set; }
  public int UPC { get; set; }

  public line(string currLine)
  {
     string[] cells = currLine.Split('|');
     int item;
     if(int.TryParse(cells[0], out item))
     {
        ItemNumber = item;
     }

     ProductStatus = cells[1];

     int upc;
     if (int.TryParse(cells[2], out upc))
     {
        UPC = upc;
     }
  }
}
```

and then:

```
string[] lines = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("\n")).Split('\n');// split it to lines;
List<line> tblLines = new List<line>();

foreach(string curr in lines)
{
    tblLines.Add(new line(curr);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so *one option* would be to take a different approach. Consider the following code:

```
// read the entire file and store each line
// as a new element in a string[]
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);

// we can skip the first line because it's
// just headings - if you need the headings
// just grab them off the 0 index
for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    var vals = lines[i].Split('|');

    // do something with the vals because
    // they are now in a zero-based array
}
```

This gets rid of that monstrosity of a connection string, eliminates the overhead of an Odbc driver, and drastically increases the readability of the code.

Comment: I finally twisted its arm:
RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Jet\\4.0\\Engines\\Text", true);
 myKey.SetValue("Format", "Delimited(|)", RegistryValueKind.String);

Answer (score 3):

It's right in the framework -- [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx).  Don't worry about the namespace, it was originally a shim for folks converting from VB6, but it's very useful.  Here's a SSCCE that demonstrates its use for a number of different delimiters:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var comma = @"one,""two, yo"",three";
        var tab = "one\ttwo, yo\tthee";
        var random = @"onelol""two, yo""lolthree";

        var parser = CreateParser(comma, ",");
        Console.WriteLine("Parsing " + comma);
        Dump(parser);
        Console.WriteLine();
        parser = CreateParser(tab, "\t");
        Console.WriteLine("Parsing " + tab);
        Dump(parser);
        Console.WriteLine();
        parser = CreateParser(random, "lol");
        Console.WriteLine("Parsing " + random);
        Dump(parser);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static TextFieldParser CreateParser(string value, params string[] delims)
    {
        var parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(ToStream(value));
        parser.Delimiters = delims;
        return parser;
    }

    private static void Dump(TextFieldParser parser)
    {
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
            foreach (var field in parser.ReadFields())
                Console.WriteLine(field);
    }

    static Stream ToStream(string value)
    {
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value));
    }
}
```